# Permission denied for www-data on samba folder

Tags: php, linux, samba

I try to access a samba folder via PHP under Ubuntu 18.04.
The structure is
.\media\documents\customers...
All files have 0755 set as permission and are owned by smbuser. When I read the directory with scandir, I get a list of all folders. But when I try to access a subdirectory, I always get a "failed to open dir: permission denied in ...".

For example:

.\media\documents\customers\clientA -> works and lists all folders

.\media\documents\customers\clientA\videos -> permission denied

It works when I change the owner to www-data, but this isn't helpful. I also tried to change the group to www-data, but that has no effect.

What else can I do?

Comment: You say that all files have 755 set as permissions, but have you checked that it is the same for folders?

Answer (score -1):

As I didn't solve my problem I created a folder under /var, sync this via cronjob and change owner of source to www-data.
It works, but it's not the solution I wanted.